# Travelling from T2 to T1 in Mumbai airport

Tags: transit, mumbai, goa-india

I have seen another thread about this but it's a little old, so I'm asking the Q again as perhaps things have changed at Mumbai Airport?

We arrive 1.10pm into T2 (International, from Muscat) and are looking to catch a flight at 4.15pm in T1.

I understand we can get a taxi which takes around 25 minutes to transit between terminals. We need to check in bags 1 hr prior to our flight (to Goa) in T1.

Do you think we will make the connection? Procedures during some airports can be slow - I don't know how efficient things are at Mumbai airport?

Thank you
Sarah

Comment: From purely anecdotal experience, it'll be a smooth connection. On my last international trip cumulating at BOM, it took me 15 minutes to get through passport control. Even taking into account you may be a foreign national, it wouldn't take more than 30 minutes.

Factoring in time spent at the luggage belt, you should be out of Terminal 2 by 1410. Even with a 40 minute terminal transit, you'll be at Terminal 1 before 1500. Airlines require you checkin luggage unto an hour before the flight, and queues at Terminal 1 are usually small, so you should be good.